# Beamer class and U3D Views

Tags: beamer, 3d, movie15, pause, keyboard

I want to switch 3D views in my presentation. I have read in the movie15 package that it is possible with the command: (dice example from movie15.pdf page 16)

```
\movieref[3Dviewindex=N]{dice}{Click here}
```

But in this case I have to click with my mouse on a button. It is possible to bind the command on a key or to call the button via a key or combine this with the command \pause ?

Regards,

Grandement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't use `movie15` anymore. Package `media9` is meant to replace it.

We can make use of a PDF feature called [*Sub-Page Navigation*](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=388) to bind `GoTo3DView` actions to the **left <-- and right -->** keyboard keypress events. Only after executing the complete sequence of actions, the Reader proceeds to the next/previous document page.

Note that this feature requires the **Full-Screen** mode.

The code below defines the command `\ThreeDPresSteps` which takes a comma separated list of `{<3D label>,<number of views>}` pairs as its argument. (Braces around pairs are mandatory, even for a single one.)

`\ThreeDPresSteps{...}` is to be used before the code of a `beamer` frame containing 3D objects. The views of the 3D objects referenced by the command are went through in the order given by the views files and in the order of `<3D label>`s in the command argument.

Remember that only the **left and right arrow** keys allow you to navigate in both directions between the presentation steps within a page. The other arrow and PgUp/PgDn keys only go in the forward direction (AR-9 for Linux).

```
...

% initialise 3D presentation steps for the next frame
\ThreeDPresSteps{{3DobjA,7},{3DobjB,5}}

\begin{frame}{...}
   \includemedia[label=3DobjA,3Dviews=3DviewsA.txt,...]{...}{...}
   \includemedia[label=3DobjB,3Dviews=3DviewsB.txt,...]{...}{...}
\end{frame}

% clear 3D presentation steps before next frame
\ThreeDPresStepsReset

...
```

**Minimal example** with two 3D objects (2 x[`dice.u3d`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/files/dice.u3d)) in a beamer frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}[2015/11/02]

%write file with 7 predefined 3D views
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{3Dviews.txt}
VIEW=Front
  ROO=27
END
VIEW=Back
  ROO=27
  C2C=0 1 0
END
VIEW=Left
  ROO=27
  C2C=-1 0 0
END
VIEW=Right
  ROO=27
  C2C=1 0 0
END
VIEW=Top
  ROO=27
  C2C=0 0 1
END
VIEW=Bottom
  ROO=27
  C2C=0 0 -1
END
VIEW=Fish Eye at Centre
  AAC=130
END
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% command to build presentation steps for navigating through 3D views
% Argument: comma separated list of {label,number of views} pairs
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\ThreeDPresSteps[1]{
  \tl_set:Nn\l_initactn_tl{}
  \clist_map_inline:nn{#1}{\tl_if_exist:cT{ann@\clist_item:nn{##1}{1}}{
    \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{}{dict}{ %init. actions for all 3D objects -> goto 1st view
      /S/GoTo3DView/V~0/TA~\use:c{ann@\clist_item:nn{##1}{1}}
    }
    \tl_put_right:Nx\l_initactn_tl{~\pbs_pdflastobj:}
  }}
  \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{}{dict}{} %reserve pdf obj for the `Next' nav. node
  \tl_set:Nx\l_nextnode_tl{\pbs_pdflastobj:}
  %primary nav. node, initialise all 3D objects in the page
  \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{}{dict}{
    /NA<</S/Named/N/NOP/Next[\l_initactn_tl]>>/Next~\l_nextnode_tl
  }
  \tl_set:Nn\l_prevactn_tl{}\tl_set:Nx\l_prevnode_tl{/Prev~\pbs_pdflastobj:}
  \tl_set_eq:NN\l_currnode_tl\l_nextnode_tl
  %register primary navigation node of this page
  \sys_if_output_pdf:TF{
    \edef\pdfpageattrsave{\the\pdfpageattr}
    \tl_set:Nx\l_temp_tl{\pdfpageattrsave/PresSteps~\pbs_pdflastobj:}
    \immediate\pdfpageattr\exp_after:wN{\l_temp_tl}
  }{
    \bool_if:NTF\g_pbs_dvipdfmx_bool{ %dvipdfmx/XeTeX
      \special{pdf:put~@thispage <</PresSteps~\pbs_pdflastobj:>>~}
    }{
      \special{ps:~
        mark~{ThisPage}~<</PresSteps~\pbs_pdflastobj:>>/PUT~pdfmark~
      }
    }
  }
  %build doubly linked list of navigation nodes
  \clist_map_inline:nn{#1}{
    \tl_if_exist:cT{ann@\clist_item:nn{##1}{1}}{
      \int_step_inline:nnnn{1}{1}{\int_eval:n{\clist_item:nn{##1}{2}-1}}{
        \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{}{dict}{} %reserve pdf obj for the `Next' nav. node
        \tl_set:Nx\l_nextnode_tl{\pbs_pdflastobj:}
        \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{\l_currnode_tl}{dict}{ %current navigation node
          \l_prevactn_tl\l_prevnode_tl
          /NA<</S/GoTo3DView/V/N/TA~\use:c{ann@\clist_item:nn{##1}{1}}>>
          /Next~\l_nextnode_tl
        }
        \tl_set:Nx\l_prevactn_tl{
          /PA<</S/GoTo3DView/V/P/TA~\use:c{ann@\clist_item:nn{##1}{1}}>>}
        \tl_set:Nx\l_prevnode_tl{/Prev~\pbs_pdflastobj:}
        \tl_set_eq:NN\l_currnode_tl\l_nextnode_tl
      } 
    }
  }
  %final navigation node
  \pbs_pdfobj:nnn{\l_currnode_tl}{dict}{\l_prevactn_tl\l_prevnode_tl}
}
\newcommand\ThreeDPresStepsReset{ %cmd for resetting pres. steps
  \bool_if:nT{
    \sys_if_output_pdf_p: && \cs_if_exist_p:N\pdfpageattrsave}{
    \immediate\pdfpageattr\exp_after:wN{\pdfpageattrsave}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Intro}
  Put the Reader into \Acrobatmenu{FullScreen}{\color{blue}Full Screen Mode} first!
\end{frame}

% initialise 3D presentation steps for the next frame
\ThreeDPresSteps{{diceA,7},{diceB,7}}

\begin{frame}{Go forth and back through 3D views using $\leftarrow$ and $\rightarrow$}
\centering

  \includemedia[
    label=diceA,
    width=0.3\textheight,height=0.3\textheight,
    activate=pageopen,deactivate=pageclose,
    3Dviews=3Dviews.txt,
  ]{}{dice.U3D}
  \includemedia[
    label=diceB,
    width=0.3\textheight,height=0.3\textheight,
    activate=pageopen,deactivate=pageclose,
    3Dviews=3Dviews.txt,
  ]{}{dice.U3D}

\end{frame}

% clear 3D presentation steps
\ThreeDPresStepsReset

\begin{frame}{The End}
  \dots
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Grandement I am about rewriting the code to also navigating the views in both directions using the PgUp/Dn keys.

Comment: This is great, I will try it today and I will consider your hint about the media15 package. I will use the media9 package for my next work.

Comment: @Grandement The current code above is quite robust. My attempt to be able to go forth and back through the views has not been successful yet.

Comment: I have tested your code and I'm really happy with this solution. A forth and back method would be nice, but in the current code is a problem. For example when you have a 3D object with 2 views and you enter the slide and you don't go to the 2nd view but you go a slide back and forth then you get the 2nd view and not again the 1th view. It is possible to fix it? Maybe your new code fixes this anyway.

Comment: @Grandement Now the forth and back method should work. The arrow keys **<--** and **-->** are required, though.

Comment: Many thanks, this version is stable and the previous problem is solved. The requirement that it is necessary to use the arrow keys or the full screen mode isn't disturbing. For a beamer presentation it is always used, so I don't see any problem and so I'm happy that isn't working in the normal mode.

Comment: Today I tried to compile this code with my new updated version of MiKTeX and  package repositories from 11/17/2015. But its faild by the control sequences with the message: Undefined control sequence. `\ThreeDPresSteps{{diceA,7},{diceB,7}}`  Has someone tried it to compile,too?

Comment: Follow-up question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331944/switching-between-u3d-views-in-beamer