# Switching between U3D views in beamer

Tags: beamer, 3d, animations, media9

for a presentation I like to switch between several views of my 3D model. 
I'd like it to behave like slides, going through one view with each click.

I found an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228989/beamer-class-and-u3d-views/229175#229175), however this solution isn't working for me. I do get the error message:

> ```
> Undefined control sequence.  \ThreeDPresSteps{{diceA,7},{diceB,7}}
> ```

This might have to do with the used media9 version, as I too get the error that only "2015/08/18" is available (latest updates on my distribution). Replacing the `media9` package by hand only brings me further down the rabbit hole, as I'll end up with "support outdated l3kernel too old" as error message.

Is there another solution or workaround? Maybe even a nicer way to change between views?

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If it's really an issue with an outdated version, can you simply update your tex distribution?

Comment: @samcarter: Thanks for the reply! I tried the linked code in the other thread, however I do get the mentioned error codes. From the comments it seems that only certain versions produce this error. I also don't really understand which part of the code produces these errors. The posted solution there seems also rather complex. So maybe there is (now) a better way to achieve this? I also can't comment on the original post due to missing reputation points.

Comment: I tried the linked code and it works perfectly fine with up-to-date pdflatex  from TeXlive2016. Can you update? [If your distribution is from mid 2015, it cannot work, as `[2015/11/02]` means it is explicitly loading this version of the package]. As far as I remember this feature to call a specific version was introduced last year, so maybe you distribution does not have it yet.

Comment: Which TeX distributio do you use (TeX Live, MiKTeX, ...) and which version number has it (check the first line of the log file). Please add this informations to your question ...

Comment: I'm use TeX Live, from the log: "pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2016/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.9.29)  2 OCT 2016 03:52" I also tried to manually install media9 and other dependencies but then I can't even compile other files, with the error "LaTeX Error: File `ocgbase.sty' not found.". So I hoped that there was another way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally got it running. I replaced all files mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124122/media9-installation-in-ubuntu-12-04) and then [ocgx2](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx2), after a rerun of `texhash /usr/local/share/texmf` it seems to work, so far I haven't found other issues. Just hope it won't collide with my package manager in the future.

Also thanks to @samcarter for the help!